# Possible to display ping to website in browser? (ie, "your ping to site: 49ms")

Tags: browser, web, ping, latency

I do hope you are all doing well! I have a question related to showing ping in a browser.  I need to make a website that displays the user's ping to that site (ie, user goes to sitename.com, and the site says "Your ping to this site is 49ms." Ideally, this would be the actual ping between the user's PC and the host server of the website.

My first question is, is this possible? My second question is, what is the most non-invasive way to do this? It would awesome if the site could achieve this function without asking the user for permissions.

Any information/insight would be greatly appreciated. Would also be wonderful if the solution allowed the user to test pings of other IP addresses!

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't possible without some extensible application/request such as seen on pingtest.net

Answer (score 1):

It is possible - when a user access your website you have his IP address so you can try to ping it and get the time which in most cases will be quite accurate. However there are a few cases where you will not be able to get the correct time

- some users can be behind firewalls that block ICMP Echo packets, so you will get no response;
- a user might be behind a NAT firewall so you will be actually pinging the firewall and not the real user IP;
- a user accessing your site via proxy will show a different IP, than his real one. Some proxies report the users IP using HTTP headers but some will not;
- asymmetric routing - not sure how much it might affect the round-trip time but it could lead to differences

The other way will be to use some plugin like Flash, Java, Silverlight etc that will run the ping from the users machine but it will probably ask for permission or will not be supported by all user browsers.

Comment: As a basic proof of concept try http://diado.net/pingme.php - in my case it was pretty close